# How to run exec from Java for netsh?

Tags: java, runtime.exec

The following works fine when i type it in directly into `cmd.exe`:

`netsh wlan connect name="Profile Name" ssid=XXXXXX`

However when i try to do this from java it does not work, neither does it throw any exception. It is silently ignored:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd netsh wlan connect name=\"Profile Name\" ssid=XXXXX ") ; `
```

How can i improve the code ?

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First try removing the `cmd` parameter (you don't need to run this interpreter, just `netsh`).

Else it may be due to whitespace characters in this command line (be careful of whitespace in SSID for example). You may want to try [Runtime.exec(String[] cmdarray)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)  or [java.lang.ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead to specify each parameter individually.

Examples:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"netsh", "wlan", "connect", "name=\"Profile Name\"", "ssid=XXXXX"});
```

or (complete example):

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("netsh", "wlan", "connect",
    "name=\"Profile Name\"", "ssid=XXXXX");
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = pb.start();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: +1 Thank you  .  but i get the same result . silently ignored .